# How do I multiply 2 public keys?

Tags: cryptography, multisig, elliptic-curve

I want to make DH-like key exchange calculating something like this:

*b = H(b<sub>0</sub>B<sub>1</sub>B<sub>2</sub>)*

But the problem is multiplication between two ec-points is not defined on ec-curve.

I know monero makes some transformations like `public key` -> `secret key` here https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/4b728d7dd48584987f53995a141baac4f886f017/src/multisig/multisig.cpp#L77:

```
  rct::key sk = rct::scalarmultKey(rct::pk2rct(k), rct::sk2rct(blinded_skey));
  crypto::secret_key msk = get_multisig_blinded_secret_key(rct::rct2sk(sk));
```

Can I use the same trick? Is it secure?

Comment: There is no such thing as multiplying two EC points together. You can only add EC points, or multiply an EC point with a scalar. You can hash an EC point to produce a scalar. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? A 3-way DH exchange? If so, see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/can-one-generalize-the-diffie-hellman-key-exchange-to-three-or-more-parties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`knacc` is right - there's no way no just multiply to ec-points. I solved my problem by making key exchange:

*b = b<sub>0</sub>b<sub>1</sub>B<sub>2</sub>*